# Does next/script module's <Script> tag supports dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, head

I was working on Next.js based codebase we recently migrated to most updated version of nextjs 11.x. For the sake of core web vitals my job is to update the old script tags (Simple HTML/JSX) to the next/scripts module `<Script>` component the old stack uses tag manager by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. how to use next/script tag and achieve the same output.

```
      <script
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-******');`
        }}
      ></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What issues are you having? You should be able to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` directly with `next/script`.

Comment: Its not working as in it is failing to injecting the code to dom

Comment: Yes it works. You might want to check your casing `"script" !== "Script"`. You might also want to explicitly set the `strategy="afterInteractive"`.  How do you know that it's not injecting into the dom?